# Can an iphone/android app connect send a request to any server?

Tags: iphone, android

I am developing an app where iphone and android phones need to send requests to different servers. Are there any restrictions on this (ie: can we only send via apple gateway)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can send requests to any server.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely send request to any server. Have a look at [`NSURLRequest`](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/&ei=uWf2Tf7pNpSwhQezkvjqBg&usg=AFQjCNFXb75nNwZUBqJek6XK94EWjavM0g) and [`NSURLConnection`](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CB8QFjAB&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/&ei=72f2TcWSG4fDhAfjluTvBg&usg=AFQjCNEulpFY25jvfnKWOjaTDopyPK1M3g) if you are interested in communicating through  the HTTP protocol.

Anyway, for HTTP communication, I strongly suggest the [ASIHTTP framework](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). It makes everything easier.

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Networking_iPhone/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007301#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007301-CH1-SW6) you can find a general overview of what networking technologies Apple offers.